# Jira Rest API call works on local program but not in plugin

Tags: java, rest, jira, unirest

I am trying to build a jira plugin which involves Jira Rest API by using Java and Unirest library.

I have a working Java program on my local computer that successfully calls the Jira Rest APIs and creates a Issue.

However, I am running into internal server errors on create issue api call.

This is how I am calling the create issue API on both my local program and the plugin where api_url, payload, and authentication are all identical. The local program yields a 201 response, while my plugin gives a 500 response.

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> createIssueResponse = Unirest.post(api_url+"issue")
        .withObjectMapper(new JacksonObjectMapper())
        .basicAuth(username, password)
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .body(payload)
        .asJson();
```

```
public static String username = "admin";
public static String password = "admin";
public static String api_url = "http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/latest/";
```

Payload is

```
{
    "fields":
    {
        "summary":"Test case of PLAT-2",
        "issuetype":{"id":"10000"},
        "priority":{"id":"3"},
        "project":{"key":"PLAT"},
        "assignee":{"name":"admin"}
    }
}
```

Side Note:

When I try to call Get Issue API, the plugin runs successfully, so it shouldn't be a problem with my authentication. However, I am using the exact same body as well, so I am really confused on what is actually causing the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

All I did was running atlas-mvn clean and atlas-mvn package. Somehow magically, I no longer get the same error response as I reconfigured my jira software.